# Section number and theorem number are not separated by the period

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

While writing with Springer latex template in https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates, I realized that it doesn't separate the section number and theorem number automatically. For instance, the first theorem in section 2 is numbered as Theorem 21., not Theorem 2.1. as usual, even though I wrote

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

in the preamble. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the user guide that comes with the pdf, it shows you can add `nospthms` as an option to the documentclass, to ignore the Springer-like environments, and this gives the desired output. It does advise checking with your editor whether this is okay.